visualize rotated point in rotation matrix
I have a default 4x4 transformation matrix consist of 3x3 rotation matrix, 3x1 translation vector and 1x3 scaling vector:
matrix_default= [[1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 1, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 1]]

I apply a translation in x-direction and visualize it using:
matrix_translated= [[1, 0, 0, 10],
                    [0, 1, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 1]]


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis')

# Visualize translation
ax.scatter(matrix_default[0, 3], matrix_default[1, 3], matrix_default[2, 3], color='r', s=10**2)
ax.scatter(matrix_translated[0, 3], matrix_translated[1, 3], matrix_translated[2, 3], color='black', s=10**2)

plt.show()


I want to also visualize if I apply a rotation in any direction, so that it is visualized as cartesian coordinate system on the drawn point as e.g. lines with arrows:

EDIT:
A 90° rotation applied on z-axis looks like in rotation matrix:
   matrix_rotated= [[-1, -2, 0, 0],
                    [2, -1, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 1]]

I want to represent this rotation using arrows/lines

I don't get what your question is. Is it a matplotlib question about "how to draw arrows" (in which case, it isn't relevant to explain all this matrix stuff). Or is it about how to compute these arrows directions?

Also, your 4x4 matrix in a 3D worlds are probably homogeneous coordinates ones. So, you should have plotted, not (M[0,3], M[1,3], M[2,3]) but (M[0,3]/M[3,3], M[1,3]/M[3,3], M[2,3]/M[3,3]).

The directions are already given currently as identity matrix (3x3) in 4x4 transformation matrix. I want to just visualize them using arrows on the points

It is really not clear for me. Are your examples accurate? Your initial_example has no rotation at all, unless I miss something. Yet your drawing shows one. And your edit shows also a rotation that should let z-axis unchanged, still not compatible with your drawing. It is hard to understand what you want if your examples do not show what you want; and if they do, then it is hard to understand what is the logic here.

From your comments, I am under the impression that all you need is to use quiver on the columns of the matrix (the 3 first. Using the 4th column as origin for the arrow). But, again, your examples say otherwise.

You can try following:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix_default = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                           [0, 1, 0, 0],
                           [0, 0, 1, 0],
                           [0, 0, 0, 1]])

matrix_translated = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 10],
                              [0, 1, 0, 0],
                              [0, 0, 1, 0],
                              [0, 0, 0, 1]])

# Rotation matricies
angle = np.deg2rad(90)

rotation_x = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, np.cos(angle), -np.sin(angle)],
    [0, np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle)]
])

rotation_y = np.array([
    [np.cos(angle), 0, np.sin(angle)],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [-np.sin(angle), 0, np.cos(angle)]
])

rotation_z = np.array([
    [np.cos(angle), -np.sin(angle), 0],
    [np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle), 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
])


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis')

# Visualize translation
ax.scatter(*matrix_default[:3,3], color='r', s=10**2)
ax.scatter(*matrix_translated[:3,3], color='black', s=10**2)

# calculate unit vectors end points
unit_vectors = np.eye(3)
unit_vectors_end_points_default = matrix_default[:3,3] + unit_vectors
# applies rotation to unit vectors
unit_vectors_end_points_translated = matrix_translated[:3,3] + rotation_z @ unit_vectors 

colors = ('b', 'r', 'k')

for end_point, c in zip(unit_vectors_end_points_default, colors):
    ax.quiver(*matrix_default[:3,3], *end_point, color=c, length=0.01)

for end_point, c in zip(unit_vectors_end_points_translated, colors):
    ax.quiver(*matrix_translated[:3,3], *end_point, color=c, length=0.01)

plt.show()


This implementation unfortunately does not visualize the directions correctly if I apply a rotation in the one of the matrices. The directions of the arrows are newer changed.

@mystic.06 didn't catch your point. You want to put cartesian coordinates unit vectors on those 2 points, right?

Could you please post the full code, i.e. the transformation? I think you just need to apply the same transformation on unit vectors, i.e. np.eye(3) of translated, if you want to show transformed unit vectors on the second point.

Actually I don't want to visualize the translation. They are already visualized as two points. I want to represent If I apply rotation on the point. Please see my edit.

I have edited the code based on your comments. Not sure what kind of transformation are you performing, I think you can reuse it to apply on unit vectors, however I've created 3 rotation matrices (clockwise) for each coordinate, and used for z coordinate.

Probably, the best way to visualize this is to apply the transformation to a vector (this is, to represent two points before and after applying the transformation matrix, preferably with different coordinates). For example:
def transform_point(p,trans_matrix):
  p = np.dot(trans_matrix[0:2,0:2],p) #rotate+scale
  p = p + trans_matrix[3,0:2] #translate

p0 = [0,0,0]
p1 = [1,1,1]
tp0 = transform_point(p0,matrix_translated)
tp1 = trnasform_point(p1,matrix_translated)

ax.scatter(p0[0],p0[1],p0[2],color='k')
ax.scatter(p1[0],p1[1],p1[2],color='r')
ax.scatter(tp0[0],tp0[1],tp0[2],color='k',alpha=0.5)
ax.scatter(tp1[0],tp1[1],tp1[2],color='r',alpha=0.5)

If it's difficult for you to visualize it with only two points, you can define the three ortonormal-base vectors instead:
p0=[0,0,0]
p1=[0,0,1]
p2=[0,1,0]
p3=[1,0,0]

and apply the transformation to all of them and then do the scatter of the four points before and after the transformation.
Note that in the case where your default_matrix is not the identity, you will have to apply it also to the original points p0,p1.
Also note that you do NOT have a 1x3 scaling vector in the matrix; the scaling factors come defined by the trace (diagonal) of the 3x3 "rotation" matrix.

A tool made specifically for this task is pytransforms3d. It has as a dependency matplotlib and numpy (so it should be directly compatible with your code) and has an extensive documentation as examples.
From the example page you have something similar :
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pytransform3d.rotations as pyrot
import pytransform3d.transformations as pytr


p = np.array([0.0, 0.0, -0.5])
a = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, np.pi])
B2A = pytr.transform_from(pyrot.matrix_from_axis_angle(a), p)

p = np.array([0.3, 0.4, 0.5])
a = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -np.pi / 2.0])
C2B = pytr.transform_from(pyrot.matrix_from_axis_angle(a), p)

C2A = pytr.concat(C2B, B2A)
p = pytr.transform(C2A, np.ones(4))

ax = pytr.plot_transform(A2B=B2A)
pytr.plot_transform(ax, A2B=C2A)
ax.scatter(p[0], p[1], p[2])
plt.show()

